# C++: passing object reference as parameter gives error: no matching function for a call to class::function()

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

Passing an object reference as parameter gives me the error:
`No matching function for a call to i2cController::i2cController`

I've also tried passing a pointer, and creating the i2cController with new.
Both tries gave me the same result.
Why is it even complaining about a call to i2cController, am I not passing the object instead of calling it?

**i2Controller (Passed object)**

i2cController.h

```
#pragma once

class i2cController
{
private:
  int foo;

public:
  i2cController(int Foo);
  void write(int value);
};
```

i2cController.cpp

```
#include <i2cController.h>

i2cController::i2cController(int Foo)
{
  foo = Foo;
}

void i2cController::write(int value)
{
  foo++;
}
```

**Led class (receiving object reference, error originating from)**
Error originates from: `Led::Led(int pin, i2cController &Controller);`
Led.h

```
#pragma once
#include <i2cController.h>

class Led
{
private:
  i2cController controller;
  int pin;

public:
  Led(int pin, i2cController &Controller);
  void turnOn();
};
```

led.cpp

```
#include <Led.h>

Led::Led(int Pin, i2cController &Controller)
{
  controller = Controller;
  pin = Pin;
}

void Led::turnOn()
{
  controller.write(pin);
}
```

**main**

```
i2cController controller(5);
Led led1 = new Led(led1Pin, controller);
```

Comment: `i2cController controller;` would need a _defaiult constructor_ unless you will assign it from a _member initializer list_ used in the `Led` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is from constructor of Led class. Constructor is trying to initialize default `i2cController controller;` field. Constructor is also looking for default i2cController constructor without parameters, which is not defined.

If you need a reference make it like the following.

```
class i2cController
{
private:
  int foo;

public:
  explicit i2cController(int Foo)
     foo(Foo) 
  {}
  void write(int value);
};

class Led
{
Led(Led&) = delete;
Led& operator=(Led&) = delete;
private:
  i2cController &controller;
  int pin;

public:
  Led(int pin, i2cController &Controller);
  ~Led() noexcept;
  void turnOn();
};

Led::Led(int Pin, i2cController &Controller)
  controller(Controller),
  pin(Pin)
{}
Led::~Led() noexcept
{}
```

If you need a copy

```
class Led
{
private:
  i2cController controller;
  int pin;

public:
  Led(int pin,const i2cController &Controller);
  void turnOn();
};

Led::Led(int Pin,const const i2cController &Controller)
  controller(Controller),
  pin(Pin)
{}
```

Comment: Making that member a reference could be too far and will have other implications.

Comment: @Slava Just make Led uncopyable, to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Led` you have `controller` as a field and you do not initialize it, but use assignment to it in `Led` constructor body, so it must be default constructed first. Solution could be to initialize it and make a copy:

```
Led::Led(int Pin, i2cController &Controller) :
    controller( Controller ),
    pin( Pin )
{
}
```

then your problem should disappear

Comment: Thanks but I wanted a reference / pointer to save memory since its for Arduino where memory is limited

Comment: You need to understand what you are doing then, you may have issue with object lifetime